# Error when starting Jupyter Notebook (iPython)

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am running Python 2.7 and have installed Jupyter Notebook using pip install.

When I try to launch the notebook from the command line by typing in

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <modul
e>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line  267, in
 launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 591
, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 75,
 in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1017, in in
itialize
super(NotebookApp, self).initialize(argv)
   File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in initialize
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 75,
 in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 243, in
 initialize
self.migrate_config()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 169, in
 migrate_config
migrate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\migrate.py", line 227, in mig
rate
if migrate_config(name, env):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\migrate.py", line 200, in mig
rate_config
cfg = loaders[ext](src).load_config()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 432, in
load_config
self._read_file_as_dict()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 464, in
_read_file_as_dict
py3compat.execfile(conf_filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\py3compat.py", line 278,
in execfile
exec(compiler(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\.ipython\profile_default\ipython_notebook_config.py", li
ne 102
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'C:\Users\Stuart\Documents\iPython'
^
 IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I can run

```
jupyter notebook --help
```

without issue so I am not sure whether it is installed incorrectly or there is some other reason why it is not running.

Could someone please suggest why I may be receiving this error message and how I can run the notebook properly?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your profile configuration, check to make sure the line mentioned is properly indented

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks - there was indeed an indent on that particular line which I have now deleted. Unfortunately I am now getting another error message, but I shall post a new question as I guess it is most likley unrelated to that previously erroneous indent. Many thanks!